# JS web word highlight problem - How to make it highlight words correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a table and I have created a rule for highlighting words in the column.

- If fit then green
- If moderate then orange
- If not fit then blue

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dataframe-container table td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
          var resultValue = $(this).text().trim();

          var highlightedValue = resultValue.replace(/\bfit\b/g, '<span class="fit">fit</span>');
          highlightedValue = highlightedValue.replace(/\bnot\sfit\b/g, '<span class="not-fit">not fit</span>');
          highlightedValue = highlightedValue.replace(/\bmoderate\b/g, '<span class="moderate">moderate</span>');

          $(this).html(highlightedValue);
        });
      });
    </script>
```

However, when I launch the code in the word "not fit" it highlights in green only the word fit. Instead of highlighting the whole phrase not fit.

Comment: Use `if` statements that test the whole value, and then add the appropriate class to the entire element, instead of replacing the word with a span.

Comment: You should check for `not fit` before `fit`, otherwise the `fit` condition will be matched.

Answer (score 0):

- You need only one `.replace()` method
- Use RegExp capturing group `()` with options (alternatives) `|`; and use space instead of `\s`
- You don't need `.each()`. `.html()` already considers every item in the collection

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  $('.dataframe-container table td:nth-child(2)').html(function() {
    const text = $(this).text().trim();
    return text.replace(/\b(fit|non fit|moderate)\b/g, (match) => {
      return `<span class="${match.replace(/ /, "-")}">${match}</span>`
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
.fit { background: green; }
.non-fit { background: red; }
.moderate { background: orange; }
```

```html
<div class="dataframe-container">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>fit foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>test moderate bar</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>other</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>is non fit</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```